# Testing a function that internally calls an async method

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a function as follows:

```
let a;
let b;

const functionThatCallsAsync = ()=> {
    a = 1;

    asyncFn().then(() => {
        b = 2;
    }).catch(() => {
        // catch stuff
    })

}
```

In the unit test:

```
describe('functionThatCallsAsync', () => {
    it('should set a and b', (done: () => void) => {
        spyOn(ctrl, 'asyncFn').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());

        functionThatCallsAsync();
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(ctrl.asyncFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(a).toEqual(1);
            expect(b).toEqual(2);
            done;
        }, 1)    
})
```

The test successfully asserts what's in the synchronous part of the function (a equalling 1) and that `asyncFn` is called but  not what's in the asynchronous part (b equalling 2). What am I missing here?

Note: `ctrl` is the controller where my function is defined which I would have created an instance of in the unit test file. `asyncFn` is assumed to be defined where `functionThatCallsAsync` is defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the unit test asynchronous expectation should go inside then function after calling `functionThatCallsAsync`function

`ctrl.asyncFn().then(() => { expect(b).toEqual(2); });`

Comment: @jjkl, Did this helped in any way?

Answer (score 0):

To test an asynchronous function in JavaScript or Angular, I use `async/await` with `fixture.whenStable()`

Something like this for your case

```
describe('functionThatCallsAsync', () => {
    it('should set a and b', async done => {
        spyOn(ctrl, 'asyncFn').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());

        functionThatCallsAsync();
        // fixture.whenStable() ensures all promises have resolved
        await fixture.whenStable();
        expect(ctrl.asyncFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(a).toEqual(1);
        expect(b).toEqual(2);
        // Call the done function to tell the test you are done with the assertions
        done();
});
```